# How to insert an excel chart into Word using AddOLEObject

Tags: excel, charts, insert, ms-word

I'm trying to create a linked OLE Object in a Word document using VB.Net.

Existing code uses InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(FileName:="abc.xlsx", LinkToFile:=True, Range:=Some Word Range) to insert a worksheet into a Word document.

I need more control than this. To select a range of cells I've found that extra information after the filename can be useful, for example: FileName:="abc.xlsx!sheet1!R1C1:R20C5"

Is there a way to specify a specific chart within a worksheet? So can I specify the second chart on the worksheet as the object to link to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help Mark.

I eventually figured out that if the Chart is in it's own sheet, rather than an object in Sheet1, then the AddOLEObject code works correctly with the following setting:

FileName:="abc.xlsx!Chart1"

I'm happy with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

A chart will either be a whole worksheet so address as per your sheet1 e.g. abc.xlsx!sheet1 or an object on a sheet so use the object name e.g. abc.xlsx!sheet1!chart_object

Comment: When I tried that (last week and again just now), the code just hangs...If that is the way to achieve it, then I will need to delve a little deeper into the code and see what the problem is.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @mmmmmm I also cannot get abc.xlsx!sheet1!chart_object to work. Could you verify that this (still) works?

Comment: No idea I have not had Excel for 10 years - but see other answer - what is your chart object actually called?

Comment: The other answer is unfortunately using chart sheets. I tried the following: oSlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject(FileName:=$"{oChartObject.Parent.Parent.Path}\{oChartObject.Parent.Parent.Name}!{oChartObject.Parent.Name}!{oChartObject.Name}", Link:=Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse)

the FileName:= results in the following string: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx!Sheet1!NameOfMyChartObject

Comment: @mmmmmm I searched online for quite a bit and could not verifiy that inserting a regular chart (i.e. not a chart sheet) works with AddOleObject. If you have any link or idea I would very much appreciate it. thanks

Comment: The place to start is the MS documents - they are complete enough the answer is there.  My guess is use that FileName if that fails create a new question

Comment: I created a new question for this. Thanks