# How do I programmatically insert, or edit, a pie chart in a Word 2007 document, using vs 2010, c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, automation

I need to programmatically insert, or edit, a pie chart in a Word 2007 document, using vs 2010, c# ...  everything I have found shows how to put these old ugly charts into a word doc.  so I am now wondering if it is even possible to manipulate the newer and better looking charts.

This one shows how to do just what I want, only it's the old ugly charts....  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178766.aspx.  It tells you to insert a OLE object, and it's the ancient msgraph.chart.8 stuff.

I've been able to do everything I need to do except use the newer style of charts.

Here's some of the code.  I built a new pie chart and now how do I insert it into the Word document?  My PieChart3D class is based on these http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

```
// here's my c#.net

private void CreateChart(string title, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc, ChartType chartType, Hashtable values)
{
  PieChart3D chart1 = new PieChart3D();  // using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
  chart1.PieChart3D_Load(values);

  object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;

  // None of these work!!!!
  wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(chart1);
  wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddChart(chart1);
  wrdRng.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(chart1);

  return;
}

// done with code
```

It seems to me I only need the last step of injecting it into the document.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you open to using OpenXML to manipulate your Word document or must the solution be Word Automation/Interop (like you show in your example)?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably add the missing parameters in your 'AddOLEControl()' call just for good measure.

[How to insert an excel chart into Word using AddOLEObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262686/how-to-insert-an-excel-chart-into-word-using-addoleobject)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384

Answer (score 1):

None of these options will actually work for you. AddChart is used to create a chart that Word already knows about - you have to use one of the known chart types. AddOLEControl and AddOLEObject both require your Chart class to be registered for COM. When you call the method, it creates a new instance of the class and adds it to the form. You can't use these methods to add an existing chart that you created in C#.

I think your best bet is to save your chart to a file using the [SaveImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456181) method, then add it to your WORD document using the [AddPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture.aspx) method. You won't be able to modify the chart in Word, you'll have to delete it and re-add it, but at least you can display the chart you created.

Answer (score 1):

I found a sample code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188909/Updating-Charts-in-Word-Document-using-OpenXML

In this code create a word cocument first. You can set its style in the word document. Then you can update the chart with just one procedure call. hope it helps.

Comment: This is actually still using the built-in charts to Word, similar to the document.AddChart method. I don't think it would be possible to use this method to add a custom chart type, like the PieChart3d type the OP is using.

Comment: Yes, OpenXML is what you need to read into for creating and editing Office 2007+ documents. I suggest downloading the OpenXML SDK from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124. Here's some more sample code for creating and working with documents: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36694/Creation-of-a-Word-2007-document-using-the-Open-XM