# How to insert an Excel chart into Word using AddOLEObject (VBA not VB)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

In this question [2262686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262686/how-to-insert-an-excel-chart-into-word-using-addoleobject) a solution is given for inserting an Excel Chart in a Word document using VB. I like this approach because it does not use Copy-Paste; the solution was:

> ...if the Chart is in it's own sheet, rather than an object in Sheet1,
>   then the AddOLEObject code works correctly with the following setting:
>
> FileName:="abc.xlsx!Chart1"

However, in VBA (in word at least) this solution does not work, seems to be fall over as soon as the '!' is added to the FileName.

Does anyone know how to use this approach in MS Word?

[Edit: added code below]

```
Sub insertChart(wbName As String)

Dim sFileName As String

sFileName = ThisDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & wbName

ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
    fileName:=sFileName, LinkToFile:=False, _
    Range:=Selection.Range

End Sub

Sub myTest()

' Excel Workbook with Chart in it. Chart is added to document IF:
' - it is in its own sheet
' - it is first sheet in workbook
insertChart "myWorkBook.xlsx"

' What fails is attempt to address a specific (or multiple)
' chart in the WorkBook by using the "myWorkBook.xlsx!Chart1"
' apparently this works in VB but not VBA...

End Sub
```

Comment: Copule of questions.... `1` You want to do this in word-vba or excel-vba? `2` Where is the chart? `3` Where do you want to insert it in the word document? `4` What is wrong with Copy-Paste Method?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout - thanks for your interest.  1. word-vba  2. the chart is in its own 'sheet' in excel  3. for the sake of an example, selection.range will work fine  4. realistically nothing wrong with copy-paste, except a) I don't want to interfere with users clipboard, and b) I want to use this other method ;-)

Comment: Also.... I should mention that the solution does work in word-vba if the chart is the first sheet in the excel workbook and filename is simply the path to said workbook (i.e. it works without the "!ChartName" appended to the FileName if the chart is the first 'sheet').

Comment: what is the exact code that you are using now?

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for sticking with.  Have updated the OP by adding code. Cheers

Comment: @SlowLearner Any chance you figured this out? I have the same problem, i.e. I cannot insert a "normal" chart, only chart sheets.

Comment: @chriscode hey, sorry I really can't remember but I don't think so as I usually add my own solution if there is not one. If you do figure it out pls share :-D